# Data required from two tables in sql using group by

Tags: mysql

[image: The two existing tables.]

Table 1 shows subjects and its components.
Table 2 shows marks for each subject and its corresponding component.
Table 2 is related to Table 1 by its primary key.

[image: This image includes the expected output data required from table 1 and table 2]

The second image shows the expected output where each row shows the count of the components for the particular subject for that particular student and also the sum of marks that student secured in that subject( sum of marks of all components in that subject).

I've tried with many numbers of group by statements but still couldn't reach the required output.
It would be of great help if a valid solution is provided. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following queries:

> Query-1:

```
SELECT sub_id, COUNT(component_id) t1_component_count
FROM table1
GROUP BY sub_id;

Output:
+--------+--------------------+
| sub_id | t1_component_count |
+--------+--------------------+
| s1     |                  3 |
| s2     |                  3 |
| s3     |                  1 |
| s4     |                  1 |
+--------+--------------------+
```

> Query-2:

```
SELECT t2.stu_id, t1.sub_id, t3.comp_cnt AS t1_component_count,
 count(t1.component_id) AS t2_component_count, sum(t2.stu_marks) total_marks
FROM table2 t2 INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.t1_id = t1.t1_id
  INNER JOIN
   (SELECT sub_id, COUNT(component_id) comp_cnt FROM table1 GROUP BY sub_id)
    AS t3 ON t1.sub_id = t3.sub_id
 GROUP BY t2.stu_id, t1.sub_id;

Output:
+--------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
| stu_id | sub_id | t1_component_count | t2_component_count | total_marks |
+--------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
| stu1   | s1     |                  3 |                  3 |         100 |
| stu1   | s2     |                  3 |                  2 |         130 |
| stu2   | s3     |                  1 |                  1 |          50 |
| stu3   | s2     |                  3 |                  1 |          30 |
| stu4   | s1     |                  3 |                  1 |          90 |
+--------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solved a big problem for me. Worked perfectly.